# Obtain xll xpaths in in R using xml2

Tags: r, xml2

In xml2 it is possible to obtain an xpath of a given node using:

```
xml_path
```

I wonder what is the fastest way to extract all xpaths from a given document. I.e. I want to find final nodes and then iterate upwards.

In essence I am trying to achieve this:

```
library(xml2)

#Read
doc <- read_xml("http://www.w3schools.com/xml/plant_catalog.xml")

#Define a funciton to extract all xpaths:
extract_all_paths<-function(x){
  if (xml_length(x)==0){
    final_vector<-xml_path(x)
  } else{
    final_vector<-list("vector")
    i<-1
    while (length(x)!=0){
      x<-do.call(c,lapply(x,xml_children))
      x_length<-sapply(x,xml_length)
      final_vector[[i]]<-x[x_length==0]
      x<-x[x_length!=0]
      i<-i+1
    }
    final_vector<-do.call(c,final_vector)
    final_vector<-sapply(final_vector,xml_path)
    final_vector
  }
  final_vector
}

#Function to extract everything for a given xpath:
function_extract_values<-function(x,y){
  paste(xml_text(xml_find_all(y,x)),collapse="&&&&")
}

format_file<-function(x){
  x<-xml_ns_strip(x)
  data_path<-data.table(x=xml_children(x))
  data_xpath<-data_path[,extract_all_paths(x),by=1:nrow(data_path)]
  data_xpath[,V1:=gsub("\\[(.*?)\\]","",data_xpath$V1)]
  data_xpath<-data_xpath[!duplicated(V1)]
  data_xpath[,V2:=list(list(x)),by=1:nrow(data_xpath)]
  data_xpath[,value:=function_extract_values(V1,V2[[1]]),by=1:nrow(data_xpath)]
  data_xpath[,V1:=gsub("\\/","_",V1)]
  data_names<-data_xpath$V1
  data_xpath[,V1:=NULL]
  data_xpath[,nrow:=NULL]
  data_xpath[,V2:=NULL]
  data_xpath<-transpose(data_xpath)
  setnames(data_xpath,data_names)
  data_xpath
}
data<-format_file(doc)
```

In essence I want to parse an .xml file and then put it as a row to the data.table. My current solution is very slow, if I have a lot of files, maybe somebody can suggest some faster solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be better ways to get a complete list of xpaths from a document, but here is one solution.  (There are also probably better ways to iterate through your xml document to get what you want, but you asked for a list of all xpaths):

```
library(XML) #This may work in xml2 but i usually stick with XML

#read document into R and select root
myXML <- xmlTreeParse("myXML.xml", useInternal = TRUE)
top <- xmlRoot(myXML)
#convert XML to list of lists
temp <- xmlToList(top)

#use names of recusive apply to get list of recusive steps through XML
temp <- unique(names(rapply(test, summary, how="unlist")))
#remove the last item created by summary function
temp <- unique(sub("\\.[^.]*$", "", temp))
#remove attributes
temp <- unique(sub("..attrs", "", temp))
#sub . for / to create xpath
temp <- sub("\\.","/", temp)
#add / to start the xpath at the docuemnt root
XPaths <- paste0("/", temp)
```

Comment: this will not work with some weird namespaces, any ideas on how to handle those ?

Comment: You could take out the weird namespaces, if you could post an example i may be able to help... However, what are you trying to do?  There is likely a better way to do it.

Comment: @The thing is as follows, I have .xml where I do not know structure what I want is to extract all possible fields!

Comment: With out knowing the structure of your XML file it is not possible to extract out all of the fields into meaningful tables, because you do not know how the fields relate to each other. There is no one standard way to format XML. For example are all tags under a given tag part of the same table or are they each separate tables and the values are attributes, or is the primary key for a table stored with its tag or at the tag above it.  There is just no way to know without looking at your data.   The  `XML::xmlElementSummary`  & `xm2::xml_structure` functions can help you explore your data.

Comment: I extended my example maybe you can propose more efficient solution

Comment: Are all of your data simple like the example or do you have more complex xml that contains data from multiple tables or on several levels? If it is more complex and you do it as you illustrated you will lose the ability to relate your data together, is that ok?

Comment: it is as I illustrated, the only thing is that I need to join some observations with &&&&

Comment: if it is as illustrated all you need to do is: `df <- XML::xmlToDataFrame("plant_catalog.xml")` followed by `myList <- lapply(df, function(x) paste0(x, collapse="&&&"))`

Comment: Unfortunately it still does not collapse my document at the right level if I more complicated .xml whereas my solution does for arbitrarly complicated dataset

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145575/discussion-between-ian-wesley-and-vitalijs).